# Traveling from the US to the UK without a passport

Tags: uk, paperwork, us-residents

I'm a permanent resident if the U.S. (green card holder) in the middle of my application for citizenship. I haven't traveled since I was a young child where I was on my mother's Ethiopian passport.

I need to travel to the UK for work but do not have a passport and won't get one in time before the trip. Can I travel to the UK with just a green card?

Comment: Duplicate of https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/56487/traveling-without-passport-just-a-green-card-between-us-and-uk

Comment: That duplicate question is where the asker is a UK citizen. Nobody has said that's the case here.

Comment: Your embassy (from your current citizenship - ethiopian?) might offer a fast-process for a passport. Contact them.

Comment: @Aganju, the Ethiopian Embassy is a mess right noe because of a regime change and personel changes. I've called a few times.

Comment: @Aganju I looked at the website and there was no indication of a fast process, only that applicants should allow 45 days.

Comment: OP should consider whether applying for some other passport would affect the citizenship application. I don't know, but sounds like the kind of thing that could do.

Comment: @RobaAdnew If you got the time, try just showing up and insist you speak with someone. It's easier to tell someone 'no' on the phone than in person. Highly unprofessional, I know, but only you and they would know and your situation is urgent. Time to bend some rules. And yes, that's why I make this a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: Note that "travelling to the UK for work" would also require a UK work visa.

Comment: @pjc50 not if the visit complies with the requirements for a business visit. If someone's employer sends her to the UK for training or meetings or any of several other reasons, the visit would be "for work" and yet not require a work visa.

Answer (score 33):

If you are an Ethiopian citizen, then you will not be able to enter the UK without an Ethiopian passport, and you would have to apply for a UK visa. There will be no way you could get a visa to enter the UK with only a green card.

Unfortunately, you may have to postpone this work trip until you obtain your US passport.

Comment: ... or an Ethiopian passport and a UK visa.

Answer (score 14):

Yes, you need a passport.  If you are unable to get an Ethiopian passport and are a refugee or asylee, you may be able to get a [travel document from the United States](https://www.uscis.gov/travel-documents) to serve in its place.  But the UK will not admit you with just a green card, so the airline won't let you get on the plane.

Comment: "If you are unable to get an Ethiopian passport and are a refugee or asylee, you may be able to get a travel document from the United States to serve in its place." You may be referring to the Refugee Travel Document, which is available to someone in asylee or refugee status, or a permanent resident who got that status through being an asylee or refugee. However, *any* permanent resident can get a Re-entry Permit (doens't need to have been a refugee or asylee).

Comment: @user102008 thanks for pointing that out. I didn't mention it because I do not know whether the UK will accept a reentry permit in lieu of a passport.  Do you?

Comment: @user102008 The UK Government website [does not mention a re-entry permit](https://www.gov.uk/uk-border-control/before-you-leave-for-the-uk).

Comment: @AndrewLeach but that site doesn't mention refugee travel documents either, and the UK does accept those.

Comment: @AndrewLeach: In any case the OP will need to apply for a British visitor visa to visit the UK. The [requirements](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa/documents-you-must-provide) for a British standard visitor visa says "When you apply you’ll need to provide a current passport or other valid travel identification" so non-passports are accepted, and it doesn't list any specific ones.

Answer (score 10):

A Green card, on its own, is only valid for entering Canada by land, or re-entering the US.

So no, you will have to cancel the trip (don't forget to get the airport taxes refunded) unless you can get an emergency travel document.

And get a passport before your next trip. You need it.

Comment: Is this answer relevant for the UK? Why does it mention Canada?

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto TO make it clear that Green cards aren't usable for entry into any other country at all

Comment: It seems I read it with the emphasis on "by land" rather than on "Canada or the US" and then I started wondering why Canada was mentioned at all. The emphasis in written form is sometimes ambiguous. I will make an edit suggestion.

Comment: OK, apparently I can't make an edit suggestion because it's less than 6 characters. My suggestion was to replace `Canada by land` with `*Canada* (by land)`.

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto Personally I don't feel such an edit is needed.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev it might depend on one's mother tongue, but in several languages (including English) the emphasis is often before a punctuation mark like a comma, unless otherwise noted. So the sentence currently can (and probably will) be read as "is only valid for entering Canada *by land*" at least by some readers. Otherwise why would you think I would have even bothered to ask about the ambiguous meaning in the first place? Just to waste my own time? :P

Answer (score -1):

If you have your ticket already, you may be able to expedite the passport application. This generally involves personally going into one of the passport centers (they are in select major cities). Information on how much you can expedite and under what conditions is available here: https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/passports/apply-renew-passport/hurry.html

Comment: This is about expediting the issuance of a _United States passport_, which the OP cannot get in the first place because they're not a citizen (yet).